# Cant use Tkinter button more than once

Tags: python, tkinter, button

im kinda new to tkinter and while working on a school project ive stumbbled a problem, the button i use to change a label cant be used more than once.
here is the full code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random, time


dic = {}

def pDic(dic):
    print(dic)

def add(dic):

    org = orgEntry.get()

    tran = tranEntry.get()

    dic[org] = tran
    tranEntry.delete(0,END)
    orgEntry.delete(0,END)

    return dic

def clear():

    labOrg.grid_remove()
    labTran.grid_remove()
    orgEntry.grid_remove()
    tranEntry.grid_remove()
    save.grid_remove()
    printDic.grid_remove()
    train.grid_remove()
    
    
def pMain(dic):

    global practiceBtn

    clear()

    i=0

    kList = list(dic)
    random.shuffle(kList)

    practiceEntry = Entry(app)
    practiceEntry.grid(row = 1 , column = 1)

    labPractice = Label(app, text = "Enter translation for: " + kList[i] )
    labPractice.grid(row = 0 , column = 1, padx = 200)

    practiceBtn = Button(app, text = "Check", command = lambda : pLoop(i,kList,labPractice,dic,practiceEntry.get()))
    practiceBtn.grid(row = 2 , column = 1)

    

def pLoop(i,kList, labPractice, dic ,entered):

    if entered== dic[kList[i]]:
        i+=1
        next(i,kList,labPractice)

def next(i,kList,labPractice):
    labPractice.grid_remove()
    labPractice = Label(app, text = "Enter translation for: " + kList[i] )
    labPractice.grid(row = 0 , column = 1, padx = 200)





app = Tk()
app.geometry('600x450+1000+60')
app.title("Dictionary")


labOrg = Label(app, text = "Enter Word")
labOrg.grid()

orgEntry = Entry(app)
orgEntry.grid(padx = 20)

labTran = Label(app, text = "Enter Translation")
labTran.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 70)

tranEntry = Entry(app)
tranEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 70)

save = Button(app, text = "Save to dictionary", command = lambda : add(dic))
save.grid(row = 2 ,column = 1,columnspan = 1, pady=10, padx=50)

printDic = Button(app, text = "print dictionary", command = lambda : pDic(dic))
printDic.grid()



train = Button(app, text = "Train", command = lambda : pMain(dic))
train.grid(row = 2, pady = 20, padx = 50)


app.mainloop()
```

right now its kinda messy (and unfinished :p)but id be thankfull if you can run my code and tell me why the practiceBtn is not working.
the point is to get a dictionary as an input when keys are words and the values are the translation, then give the user a way to practice those words by cycling through all of them.

Comment: You can try adding `global labPractice` to the start of your `next` function. Even better try using `labPractice.config(text=<new text>)` instead of hiding the last `labPractice` Label and creating a new one.

Comment: Didnt know i could do that, ill try it. Thanks